# How can I hide a date value if it is less than current date?

Tags: asp.net

I have the following date dropdownlist options:

```
<asp:DropDownList id="eventsDate" runat="server">
   <asp:ListItem Value="04/31/2012">Apr 31, 2012</asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem Value="05/21/2012">May 21, 2012</asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem Value="07/22/2012">Jul 22, 2012</asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem Value="10/16/2012">Oct 16, 2012</asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem Value="11/12/2012">Nov 12, 2012</asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem Value="12/18/2012">Dec 18, 2012</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

If any of the dates in the dropdown is less than today's date, hide it.

For instance, today's day is April 26, 2012. Assuming that the first date on the dropdownlist is April 25, 2012, it should not show up on the dropdownlist.

I am drawing blanks.

Comment: How are you generating the list of dates?

Comment: Currently, I have them as static dropdownlist. I am in the process of adding them to the database to a table called DateLists.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should stop it in the datasource itself - since it doesnt have any event method for pre-binding ( like repeater does - ItemCreated Event)...

so if your dataTable has all values you should filter it like :

```
var myNewData = (from  a in dt.AsEnumerAble() where DateTime.Parse(a["time"])<DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(1) select a).CopyToDataTable()
```

### edit

the DropDownlist control doesnt have any method which tells you   : "ok im gonna add a new item which you can check him and tell me to add it or not"

yu dont have this function in DropDownlist.

the only option ( which i see) is to filter it when you get the results.

assuming you get it in datatable-  you should create a new datatable which holds ONLY THE RELEVANT ITEMS.

the code which i wrote is in Linq2XML.

you just need to add :

using system.linq;

Comment: You may want to use `<DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(1)` because otherwise you'll be including time in the decision.

Comment: Thanks guys, Royi especially. Your proposed solution is good but it is a bit too complicated for me. Is it possible to explain a bit in detail? For instance, I can create a date table and enter these dates on the db.

But I am not sure how to use your suggested solution. Thanks a lot again for your kindness.

Comment: If it is easier to disable a date in the dropdown based on the condition I gave or to remove it only from the dropdown, I would be glad to try that. I am still very confused with Royi's solution which I think is cool. I just can't wrap my head around it. I am usig vb.net

Comment: I was able to figure out a way to make it work by using compareTo function without having to populate the dropdown from the db.

Answer (score 1):

If you can filter it from the datasource that's your best bet, but if not try something like this:

```
eventsDate.Items.Cast<ListItem>().Select(
    i => i.Attributes["display"] = DateTime.Parse(i.Value) >= DateTime.Today ? "block" : "none");
```